# Why does the modifier access for the properties need to be public with Unity?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Why does the modifier access for the properties need to be public with Unity?

I'm very interested in a detailed explanation for my question. I read about tips to do it in other ways, but not a detailed explanation about why this can't be declared explicitly in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you need to inject private properties?  That's not what DI is for.  Injecting private properties would violate encapsulation.

One of the constructor overloads on your class should specify everything the class needs to instantiate.  If the class can't specify what it needs in it's public API, then it doesn't need it.

From http://natpryce.com/articles/000783.html (emphasis mine):

> There are two aspects to Dependency Injection. Firstly, an object's
>   interface should define the services that the object requires as well
>   as those it provides. Secondly, the code that satisfies the
>   requirements of an object by giving it a reference to the services of
>   is collaborators **is external to both the object and its collaborators.**
>   For this reason, the pattern also used to be called "third-party
>   binding" or "third-party connect": some third party is responsible for
>   connecting and satisfying the service requirements of a component (the
>   party of the first part) with those provided by another component (the
>   party of the second part).
>
> The name "Dependency Injection" only relates to the second aspect. And
>   worse, makes it sound like dependencies are "injected" through the
>   object's encapsulation boundary rather than explicitly defined as part
>   of the object's API. And so we get "dependency injection" APIs, like
>   that in JavaEE 5, **which use reflection to poke dependencies into an
>   object's private fields**, bypassing the constructor, adding a great
>   deal of complexity to client & test code while not providing the
>   benefits that the Dependency Injection pattern should deliver.

Comment: Enh, I've done this quite a bit when it would be improper for the dependency to be exposed publically on an object - which tends to be all the time.

Comment: If it's not a public dependency, then it doesn't need to be provided from the outside.  Private dependencies should be furnished by the class itself.  I'd love to see an example of what you're describing, because it pretty much flies in the face of everything I've learned about OOP.

Comment: And how do you suggest furfilling private dependencies that need to be controlled by the application but would be laborous to wire in via constructors (like happens with plug-ins). I'm not trying to argue, but am curious. In my scenario, the class doesn't know what concrete implementation of... say a strategy to use so it can't make it itself.

Comment: I don't know.  But I would have though of some other way... any other way... than manipulating private variables from the outside.  Down that path lies Reflection and other hackery madness.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/934930  I am intrigued, however, at the very idea.

Comment: @Telastyn: Anyway, I just assumed that the way you specify a concrete implementation is by providing an Interface in the constructor, and then injecting the specific concrete object you want that fulfills the Interface contract.

Comment: @Telastyn Don't `new` up the object yourself, let your container give you the instance and resolve all the dependencies as needed.

Comment: @Mike - I understand the concept, but if the container is doing all the resolution - and you want/need the container to do it (otherwise, you wouldn't be using an IoC container) why allow public injection and force the dependency to be exposed in a type that might not necessarily want it to be? I don't think my current work is that far out from the norm... (we just use private injection and everyone ignores the concrete type).

Comment: @Telastyn 1) Manual DI should be possible as well. An IoC container is just a convenience. Preferably the your class doesn't even know there is such thing as IoC containers or even worse which one you're using. 2) The IoC container is external to the object, so it should go through the public API. Either calling a public constructor, or setting a public property.

Comment: @Telastyn Taking a dependency in the constructor does not mean it has to be exposed as a public property of the object. `public MyClass(IDependency dep) { this.prviatevar = dep; }` `var myInstance = Container.Resolve<MyClass>();`

Comment: Enh. I disagree, but this isn't the place for a conversation.

Comment: If your DI container is injecting dependencies into private fields using reflection trickery, how are you injecting mocks into your unit tests? Having dependencies in the public interface is perfectly consistent with Tell Don't Ask, and I'm not even sure what anyone would hope to gain by violating encapsulation to avoid doing it.